# How to expand the height of a list as the list grows?

Tags: html, css, angular

I have this angular component in nav-bar from application

[image]

This component basically will list items favourited by the user.
We can have 1 item,2 items, or 10 items on the list.

**I would like to do something in CSS to change the height from this component based on the length of the favourite list.
How can I do it in order to grow the height of the my component based on length of the list**

My code:

```css
.favorite-notification-panel {
  height: calc(43vh - 100px);
  width: 900px !important;
  overflow: hidden;
  right: -176% !important;
  top: 38px;
}
```

```html
<!-- FAVORITE ITEMS-->
<ul id="favorite_panel" [@mobileHeaderNavRight]="navRight" class="nav-right profile-menu-aling notification-bell">
  <li class="user-profile header-notification favorite-pointer" (clickOutside)="favoritePanelOutsideClick($event)" [ngClass]="favoriteDevicesNotificationClass">
    <a href="javascript:" (click)="toggleFavoriteNotification()">
      <img _ngcontent-c2="" class="fav-icon-align" src="assets/images/widget/ic_star_menu.png" />
    </a>

    <!-- component from favorite items -->
    <app-favorite-devices class="profile-notification favorite-notification-panel" [@notificationBottom]="favoriteDevicesNotification" [ItemsFavorited]="itemFavorited">
    </app-favorite-devices>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: By default HTML elements grow to fit their children, unless their children have special positioning rules that remove them from DOM sizing calculation (which you should rarely do). What happens when you simply remove the height property? If you need a minimum height, you can always use min-height and hope for the best.

Comment: When I remove the height property the component not showed.

Answer (score 0):

```
    .favorite-notification-panel {
   height:fit-content;
   min-height: calc(43vh - 100px);
   width: 900px !important;
   overflow:hidden;
   right: -176% !important;
   top: 38px;
}
```

Comment: Hi @Johann, welcome to StackOverflow. Answers that are nothing more than a block of code don't provide much useful insight, knowledge, or context to the OP or anyone that may come later. Take a look at [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and consider updating your answer.